# How to unite three tasks in gulp at one?

Tags: gulp

I have such tasks in my gulpfile:

```
// TTF to EOT, OTF, WOFF, SVG + font-face.css
gulp.task('fontmin', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/fonts/*.ttf')
        .pipe(fontmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/fonts'))
});

// all font-face.css files to app/fonts.css
gulp.task('fface',['fontmin'], function(){
    return gulp.src('app/fonts/*.css')
        .pipe(concat('fonts.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
});

// Removes font-face.css from app/fonts
gulp.task('fonts', ['fface'], function(){
    return del.sync('app/fonts/*.css')
});
```

I wanna optimize my gulpfile and unite this tasks at one. I've tried to use **merge-stream**, but in doesn't work (only started 'fontminify'):

```
gulp.task('fonts', function() {

    var fontminify = gulp.src('app/fonts/*.ttf')
        .pipe(fontmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/fonts'));

    var fface = gulp.src('app/fonts/*.css')
        .pipe(concat('fonts.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));

    var remove = del.sync('app/fonts/*.css');

    return merge(fontminify, fface, remove);
});
```

Comment: That doesn't actually sound like a merge-stream problem.  Does your 'fonts' task work if you remove the merge() call?  Perhaps try https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-merge - it looks pretty easy to set up.

Comment: @Mark
Yes, it works, but only makes 'fontminify'. Perhaps i don't understand how does merging work. Is it possibly at all to use several 'dest' in one function? Or only my first version can work?